# Entire object not visible in render

Tags: rendering

When I go to render my object, only the cylinders at the rear show up. I have a sun in the scene to provide light, and I checked to make sure the camera next to my object wasn't selected too.  Can anyone explain why I can't see anything?

[image: here is the rendered view]
[image: here is the view from the camera in object mode]
[image: menu]

Comment: Share a screenshot of your entire outliner and or upload the file somewhere and edit the link into your post.

Comment: Thought you might have restricted the object from rendering but everything looks ok, it will be speculative answers at most without seeing the file as there are several possible reasons as to why this is so.

Comment: Can you upload the blend? I'm guessing the material is trying to use nodes, but it could be anything.

Comment: I'm not sure how to upload the blend...I just started working with Blender, sorry.  However, under the Materials menu it says 'no material node selected', I don't know if that's helpful though.

Comment: The nodes were the problem! Thank you so much!

Comment: lavajava31, in the future when you would like to upload a .blend file you can upload it to PasteAll.org and paste the link here.